# Unable to delete record from table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to delete records from one of the tables in BigQuery, but getting 
DML over table dataset.tablename is not supported

I am using this command to delete

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'delete from dataset.table_name where Day = 20161215'
```

But it works when I tried to run it from the console like

```
delete from dataset.table_name where Day = 20161215
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would see this error if you try DML against partitioned table, which is not yet supported by DML

If this table is not partitioned  - check if it is under streaming inserts (check if it has streaming buffer or not)

See more about DML's [Known Issues](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#known_issues)